# Triple up, pair off, and single out

Tags: wordplay, river-crossing

Can you transform this word triple

```
PELTS  SORES  DIVAN
```

into this word triple

```
PLOTS  DIVES  SANER
```

just by swapping pairs of letters?

You may swap any pair of letters you like, either between two words (e.g., `TRIES` and `NODES` can swap the "T" and the "D" to become `DRIES` and `NOTES`) or within the same word (e.g., `MODES` can swap its own "M" with its own "D" to become `DOMES`).  However, after each swap, we should see a triple of English words.

Inevitably with this kind of puzzle, the question comes, "What exactly constitutes an English word?  Which word list or dictionary should we use?"  There is at least one solution to this puzzle using very common words, and at least one solution incorporating more obscure words.  Either solution is acceptable, but you are encouraged toward the more common words because it is more fun for everyone.

Also acceptable are widely-used proper nouns and adjectives, such as `DUTCH`, `DANES`, `SLAVS`, and `WELSH`.

---

Bravo to @AxiomaticSystem for finding such a concise solution!

I have also presented an alternative solution using only the most common words for those who might be pursuing that path.  It's not nearly as succinct.

Comment: Must the words in the triple end up in the given order? e.g. would a solution leading to `PLOTS SANER DIVES` work?

Comment: river-crossing?

Comment: @bobble – The words in the final triple must appear exactly as presented, so PLOTS  DIVES  SANER only.  Consider it to be three words in a single string and you are performing a string transformation in a series of steps.

Comment: @RobPratt  – Yes, because you starting at one state and trying to cross to another state through a series of steps, some of which might appear like going backward.  (In a way, it's also a maze, in the sense of navigating the graph of states.)

Comment: Fascinating puzzle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can do so in fifteen transpositions:

> [image: Changing of the three words, check table below]

For accessibility:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pelts | Sores | Divan |
| Pe**s**ts | **L**ores | Divan |
| Pests | Lo**s**er | Divan |
| Pests | Lo**n**er | Diva**s** |
| P**a**sts | Loner | Div**e**s |
| Pasts | L**i**ner | D**o**ves |
| Pasts | Line**d** | **R**oves |
| Pasts | Line**s** | Rove**d** |
| **L**asts | **P**ines | Roved |
| **S**a**l**ts | Pines | Roved |
| S**la**ts | Pines | Roved |
| Sl**o**ts | Pines | R**a**ved |
| **P**lots | **S**ines | Raved |
| Plots | **D**ines | Rave**s** |
| Plots | Dines | **S**ave**r** |
| Plots | Di**v**es | Sa**n**er |

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution which uses only the most common words:

> PELTS  SORES  DIVAN
>   PELTS  ROSES  DIVAN
>   PESTS  ROLES  DIVAN
>   RESTS  POLES  DIVAN
>   RENTS  POLES  DIVAS
>   RANTS  POLES  DIVES
>   PANTS  ROLES  DIVES
>   PANTS  SOLES  DIVER
>   PANTS  LOSES  DIVER
>   PANTS  DOSES  LIVER
>   PANTS  ROSES  LIVED
>   PANTS  SORES  LIVED
>   PANES  SORTS  LIVED
>   PAVES  SORTS  LINED
>   SAVES  PORTS  LINED
>   SAVED  PORTS  LINES
>   RAVED  POSTS  LINES
>   ROVED  PASTS  LINES
>   ROVED  LASTS  PINES
>   ROVED  SALTS  PINES
>   ROVED  SLATS  PINES
>   ROVED  SLAPS  TINES
>   ROVED  SNAPS  TILES
>   LOVED  SNAPS  TIRES
>   LOVED  SPANS  TIRES
>   LOVED  SPANS  RITES
>   LOVED  SPINS  RATES
>   LOVER  SPINS  DATES
>   LOVER  SPITS  DANES
>   LOVER  SPATS  DINES
>   LOVES  SPATS  DINER
>   DOVES  SPATS  LINER
>   DIVES  SPATS  LONER
>   DINES  SPATS  LOVER
>   DANES  SPITS  LOVER
>   DATES  SPINS  LOVER
>   RATES  SPINS  LOVED
>   RITES  SPANS  LOVED
>   TIRES  SPANS  LOVED
>   TILES  SPANS  ROVED
>   TILES  SNAPS  ROVED
>   TINES  SLAPS  ROVED
>   PINES  SLATS  ROVED
>   PINES  SALTS  ROVED
>   PINES  LASTS  ROVED
>   LINES  PASTS  ROVED
>   LINES  POSTS  RAVED
>   LINED  POSTS  RAVES
>   LINED  PORTS  SAVES
>   LINED  SORTS  PAVES
>   LIVED  SORTS  PANES
>   LIVED  SORES  PANTS
>   LIVED  ROSES  PANTS
>   LIVER  DOSES  PANTS
>   DIVER  LOSES  PANTS
>   DIVES  LOSER  PANTS
>   DIVES  LONER  PASTS
>   DOVES  LINER  PASTS
>   LOVES  DINER  PASTS
>   LOVER  DINES  PASTS
>   LONER  DIVES  PASTS
>   LOSER  DIVES  PANTS
>   LOSES  DIVER  PANTS
>   DOSES  LIVER  PANTS
>   ROSES  LIVED  PANTS
>   SORES  LIVED  PANTS
>   SORTS  LIVED  PANES
>   SORTS  LINED  PAVES
>   PORTS  LINED  SAVES
>   POSTS  LINED  RAVES
>   POSTS  LINES  RAVED
>   PASTS  LINES  ROVED
>   LASTS  PINES  ROVED
>   SALTS  PINES  ROVED
>   SLATS  PINES  ROVED
>   SLAPS  TINES  ROVED
>   SNAPS  TILES  ROVED
>   SNAPS  TIRES  LOVED
>   SPANS  TIRES  LOVED
>   SPANS  RITES  LOVED
>   SPINS  RATES  LOVED
>   SPINS  DATES  LOVER
>   SPITS  DANES  LOVER
>   SPATS  DINES  LOVER
>   SPATS  DIVES  LONER
>   SPATS  DOVES  LINER
>   SPATS  LOVES  DINER
>   SPATS  LOVER  DINES
>   SPITS  LOVER  DANES
>   SPOTS  LIVER  DANES
>   SPOTS  DIVER  LANES
>   SLOTS  DIVER  PANES
>   SLOTS  DINER  PAVES
>   PLOTS  DINER  SAVES
>   PLOTS  DINES  SAVER
>   PLOTS  DIVES  SANER